# What exactly is daily vote limit?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, up-votes

I know about Daily Vote Limit, I thought it was 40 iff your question-upvotes to answer-upvotes ratio is high I've been on MathSE since this morning (I'm in India).

You need to take a look at this image.

[image]

Why is my vote count 41 ?

Comment: No bug here, by design due to deleted posts.